# Jquery XML find where attribute equals a specific value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, find

I have a Jquery website that pulls and displays a specific value from an XML source that is structured like so

```
<alerts>
<alert type="FIRE" status="CLEAR" id="xxxxxx" client_id="xxxxxx" grouping="xxxxxx">
    <alert_location name="xxxxxx"/>
    <template name="FIRE_CLEAR"/>
</alert>
    <alert type="LIGHTNING" status="CLEAR" id="xxxxxx" client_id="xxxxxx" grouping="xxxxxx">
    <alert_location name="xxxxxx"/>
    <template name="LIGHTNING_CLEAR"/>
</alert>
```

it collects the Lightning template name value being **"LIGHTNING_CLEAR"** in jquery by using:

```
var lightXML = $(xml).find('template').eq(1).attr("name");
```

This works fine until the xml provider removes the fire alerts for winter and then i have to edit the code every 6 months to use

```
var lightXML = $(xml).find('template').eq(0).attr("name");
```

I have searched for some answers without luck but is it possible to use find to ensure it always pulls the attribute value from the alert where type="LIGHTNING"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector to find the `template` by the `name` attribute:

```
var lightXML = $(xml).find('template[name="LIGHTNING_CLEAR"]').attr("name");
```

The same using an interpolated variable:

```
var templateName = 'FIRE_CLEAR'; // or 'LIGHTNING_CLEAR'
var lightXML = $(xml).find(`template[name="${templateName}"]`).attr("name");
```

Comment: Thank you, i accepted this as the answer but forgot to mention in my original post that LIGHTNING_CLEAR is dynamic and changes, i tweaked your answer to suit my needs.

var lightXML = $(xml).find('alert[type="LIGHTNING"]').find('template').attr("name");